# updating values with firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase ref and I want to update the ref of the firebase but my app crashes when ever I try it `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFBoolean' (0x2106be078) to 'NSDictionary'`

my ref looks like this below

```
Database.database().reference(forLastMsg: championId).child(toID).updateChildValues(withValues)
                                Database.database().reference(forLastMsg: toID).child(championId).updateChildValues(withValues)
```

even using `setValue` crashes the app too.

I am actually constantly listning to the refs that is been updated so on valueChange

```
for snapshot in snapshot.children {
                        let receivedMessage = (snapshot as! DataSnapshot).value as!
                            NSDictionary
...
```

[image]

Comment: post database structure

Comment: I have added the structure

Comment: can you show the code ref you listen to , also preferably with static names to follow it instead of your dynamic variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update

```
let newVal = //// some dictionary 
 // you may add komal_xyz as dynamic according to your logic
Database.database().reference().child("komal_xyz/\(id)").updateChildValues(newVal) { (err, ref) in

}
```

To listen

```
Database.database().reference().child("komal_xyz/\(id)").observe(.value) { (ref) in
   //  

   let res = ref.value as! [String:Any]    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to update it in such way

```
let updateDatabase = databaseReference.child("something").child(someId)

    let data = [
        "boolValue": myBoolean,
        "dateUpdated": Date().toSeconds()
        ] as [String : Any]

    updateDatabase.updateChildValues(data)
```